# How can I create react app facing this problem

Tags: reactjs

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...a0","tarball":"https:'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Shahid\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-05-16T09_06_31_650Z-debug.log

Comment: you need to give more details, how this happen, code

Comment: and as the error says, lock and the log inside the file

Comment: you get this problem when u want to create a new project ??? , post the log file here